# Safari favorites icons are displayed as transparent images even though they're not

Tags: macos, safari, favicon, favorites, apple-touch-icon

I was trying to change a Safari favorites icon that gets displayed when opening a new tab. I changed some icons by changing the default images in the "/Users/MyUsername/Library/Safari/Touch Icons Cache/" Images folder. Most of the replaced icons are displayed perfectly but some appeared (I think) to be identified by Safari as a transparent background icon and proceeds to display it as one—even though it's not.

[This is the icon that Safari displayed correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wy9mt.png)

[This is the icon that Safari displayed incorrectly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPZEr.png)

Any idea how I can get Safari to display it as it should?

I've followed the criteria of the icons such as having a .png extension and being 144x144.

[This is the info for the image used for the CNN icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7GGV.png)

[This is the info for the image used for the Triplebyte icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYuDr.png)

What I've tried:

1. Reducing the size of the image
2. Changing the color profile

Is this issue actually related to the website I'm trying to get my icon for or an issue with the image file?

Comment: I'm on macOS Catalina version 10.15.4. In Mojave, this wouldn't happen since only when updating to Catalina where Safari's favorites page (new tab) has some sort of a border surrounding an icon if that particular icon happens to have a transparent background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using another image that was used as an icon by another site. Safari also displayed it as a transparent background image. It turned out that the image file wasn't the issue.

The solution to this is to just use an image that actually has a transparent background.